# Make someone understand the difference between somethings

Tags: word-usage, word-request, alternatives

I wrote:

> For example, **to teach** the student the difference between short and long vowels, like /ԑ/ and /i:/ (as set and seat) or /ɪ/ and /aɪ/ (as twin and twine), appropriate word lists can be prepared.

But I feel **teach** is much for this sentence. Maybe other verbs or just saying:

> For example, **to make** the student **understand** the difference between short and long vowels, like /ԑ/ and /i:/ (as set and seat) or /ɪ/ and /aɪ/ (as twin and twine), appropriate word lists can be prepared.

Are there better alternatives for this sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Teach" is absolutely fine. But you could say "to *help* the students understand…" "To make the students understand…" is wrong and sounds like you are trying to force the students to understand, which is impossible: the students can only understand something for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

> To *familiarize* the student *with* the difference ....

From [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/familiarize):

> **familiarize**
>
> 1         Give (someone) knowledge or understanding of something: 
>        *‘to* familiarize *pupils* with *the microscope and its uses’*
>
> 1.1     Make (something) better known or more easily grasped: 
>        *‘exercises which will help to* familiarize *the terms used’*